# How can I configure Arduino after programming it (for post upload wifi configuration)?

Tags: wifi, communication

I would like to make a device that can take a photo, and send it to a website over wifi. I'm using an Arduino Uno, a ArduCam OV2640 module, and ESP8266 Serial WIFI module. Eventually I'd like to take it off the board as a stand alone project for permanent use.

The wifi works fine, but requires a serial communication to configure. I would like to make it so that I can plug the device into a computer (via something like micro usb), change the WIFI settings, and save those settings for future reboots.

If there anyway I can do this with an Arduino interface? If not, what could I use instead?

Comment: There are firmware versions for the ESP8266 that will try to connect to wifi. And if it can't it will create an access point for any wifi device to connect to. After that you can load a webpage on the ESP that enables you to change the WiFi settings. (I think something like [this  one](http://horaciobouzas.com/2014/12/24/esp8266-based-web-configurable-wifi-general-purpose-control-part-ii/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Gerben's suggestion about putting the ESP8266 into Wireless Access Point mode and then providing access to your configuration settings via a web interface.  I've been dealing with the same question myself and this might be a workable solution.  The only downside is the amount of code required to get an ESP8266 to function as a WAP, provide a web-based UI, switch between configuration and running mode, etc.

Another idea that isn't as elegant, but would require a lot less code: Just store your configuration on an SD card, and add an SD card to your project using a separate board or shield.  You could edit the configuration by plugging it into a PC and editing the configuration file, then plug the card into your project which would read its configuration from the SD Card.

Comment: I had no idea that I could use the ESP8266 as an access point. I'll give that a try, but the backup idea works quite well for this project, thanks.